# Is scrollbar automaticly build in an app?

Tags: android, text, scrollbar

I am writing an app, where at the end it displays text- and actually much text, because even 40 lines and maybe more. Problem is, in emulator I can't scroll down the screen to see the whole text.

My question is:
 do I have to turn on the scrollbar, or anything that will allow the user to scroll down and see all the results?

or it's automaticly added, something like scrollbar at web page, where it's defaultly on?

edit:

the xml goes like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity4" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_promil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text_e"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_e"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="promil" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_e"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:text="e" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_alkomat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_promil"
    android:text="Spadek stezenia alkoholu w Twojej krwi:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I try to add < ScrollView > at the beginning and < / ScrollView > at the end, I've got errors in these two, first lines of relative layout:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

LAST EDIT:
Sorry, shoud have known that those two must lines be cut n' paste to scroll view, and then everything works properly. I'm new to XML, and that was created by graphical creation, so then I really didn't know what there was written. However everything works, and that is thanks to You guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not automatically, you need to add it to your xml. Your `ScrollView` needs to have just one child. If you want to add more than one textviews on the scrollviews, add a relative or linear layout inside the `ScrollView`, and then your multiple `TextView` inside this layout. See the following code with one `TextView`:

```
<ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="your text"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

And the following code with mutiple `TextView`:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="your text"
        />
       <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="your text 2"
       />
       <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="your text 3"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ScrollView` in your layout as a parent. And keep your `TextView` or any layout as a child of this `ScrollView`

Example,

```
 <ScrollView>
     <TextView />
 <ScrollView>
```

For more information, http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: could you look at xml layout I just posted?

Comment: I see you figured out those XML errors. And if my answer helped you, please mark it as answer :)